# make all images in sidebar same sized?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sidebar

I want to display items in wordpress sidebar with same size 45*60.Im able to adjust width to my custom size but not height.As a result sidebar images have slight difference in height.I tried CSS height and width property.It works but images doesnt display properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need more information but assuming they're images inside list items in an un-ordered list, html like this

```
<ul class="this-is-my-ul-class>
  <li><img></li>
  <li><img></li>
  <li><img></li>
</ul>
```

css like this:

```
.this-is-my-ul-class li immg {
  width: [how much width you want]px;
  height: [how much height you want]px;
}
```

Comment: here it is with images at the same size (45 * 60), but I'm assuming this isn't what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/1ryqejyo/